# Importing torchvision to conda environment - Windows

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch, torchvision

I have recently installed python (3.7.4) and conda (1.7.2) on my computer (OS: Windows 10).

I installed pytorch (1.3.1) and torchvision (0.4.2) using the conda prompt.

I created a new environment in the conda "Environment" tab.
When I try to search torchvision in my environment I can't see it in  the search result (even when I search "All" and not just "Installed").
However, when I switch to the "base(root)" environment, I can see torchvision.

How can I install torchvision to my environment?
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would help to know exactly what commands you ran at each step so people can help more quickly. In this case, it seems like you simply ran `conda install` or `pip install` while on the base env. Have you run `conda activate yourenvironmentname` ?

Comment: Yes! Thank you!
I didn't know there was an activation needed for the environment...